# How to share id between readonly source table and updating table

Tags: sql, oracle, primary-key

I have two tables: first one A is readonly,source table and the second one B is being updated in application flow (inserting new data). Let’s assume that I want to populate table B with new source data from A and one of the A id’s is already ‚taken’ by B via some insert. How to prevent from these kind of events?

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for merge syntax, which is Oracle implementation of the  *upsert* query (aka update/insert).

It goes like that:

```
merge into tableb b
using tablea a on (a.id = b.id)
when matched then
    update set b.col1 = a.col1
when not matched then
    insert(id, col1, col2, col3) values(a.id, a.col1, a.col2, a.col3)
```

The `using` clause has an `on` part that defines the join condition between the tables.

The `matched` clause describes what to do when a conflict occur: here, you can update some other column.

The `not matched` clause performs the actual insert.

Comment: Thank you @GMB for you answer. I know merge syntax. I meant that situation: In table source A I have id which is unique, I insert into table B some row with autogenerated the same id number. But in real row A <> row B. That shoudn’t happen. Any ideas?

Comment: @rafal0502: why try to insert and autoincremented key in `tableb`? Instead, you could have a separate autoincremented key on `tableb`, and not try to copy if from the other table.

Comment: I operate on attributes varchar2(char 1500). I have source table A, which is daily updated by jobs. Table B has raws from table A with additional data generated by application users. I wanted to get rid off joins on varchars that’s why I’m thinking on id’s

Comment: What do you want to do when there is a conflict on the key?

Comment: Generally that’s  my question. How to generate unique id between two tables based on varchar2 column to speed up queries and in that way get rid off conflicts

Comment: If you want to avoid conflicts and always insert new rows, don't use the varchar column as a key in the target table; use an autoincremented id instead. If you want to deal with conflicts, then, again: what do you want to do when there is one: insert, update, replace, ignore...?

Comment: But if I will use autoincrement id in target table there could be situation that ‚someone’ will provide different data with the same id in the source table. So to identify the real value of row I need to check varchar column. So the only solution is to stay with varchars as key, or try index based on function and convert varchars to id’s?

Comment: @rafal0502: we need a clear problem statement... For this, you need to define what you want to do with duplicate.

Comment: I want to mark duplicate in target table by flag unactive and use data from source table instead

Comment: @rafal0502: ok, that's clear. Well, you can do this with the above `merge` syntax. Use the `WHEN MATCHED` clause to set the flag and reset the values from the source when there is a conflict.

Comment: You meant target? Ok, but the main problem is with performance. Marge is good for sets of data, no couple rows. In merge I still need to provide on clause - which columns should I use? Using varchars will decrrase performance, using id’s as I said is complicated because there could be situation that i have the same id’s in these two tables but varchars are different

Comment: Don't worry about the tiny performance difference between varchars and int; that's premature. First, write a `merge` query that does what you want, and test it. You can always add indexes on the the `varchar` column in the tables later on to speed up things.

Comment: Yeah I even measure usability of these indexes. It’s low because I have mainly long titles in that crucial varchar column